# Why Vaadin than Groovy and Grails?

Tags: grails, vaadin

What is exact advantage it will give a framework like `Vaadin` over `Groovy and grails` ?

Do you code native Java on `Vaadin` ?

Comment: here is a mindbender: you can use vaadin _with_ grails!

Answer (score 1):

In Grails you write Groovy, produce traditional webpage like applications and use the command line tool to generate a lot of code. It is a full stack tool

With Vaadin you write Java, produce desktop like one-page ajax application and it is a UI framework.

Different tools for for different purposes and tastes.

Comment: i mean could replace THE UI staff handling for vaadin and do your business logic on groovy when using grails?

Comment: @danielad yes, that's the reason why there is a grails plugin for vaadin

Comment: You can write Groovy in Vaadin as well

Comment: Check out http://vaadinongrails.com/. I think that is what you are looking for. I have no idea of the level of it and how supported it is, but at least it reflects what you are looking for?